# How can I throw an error from within a catch, without it being an UnhandledPromiseRejection

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise, try-catch, throw

if I just throw a random error, my code works fine:

```
throw new Error('you got error')
```

but if I want to throw it from within a .catch statement, like so:

```
message.react(e).catch(()=>{throw new Error('you got error')});
```

Then I get the error gets logged like so: `(node:21609) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: you got error`, and doesn't get caught by my higher up error handler:

```
//errors from within catch() don't reach this
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err){ console.log('error caught', err); });
```

I don't want to use promises, but unfortunately this is from an lib where i don't have a choice.

How can I throw the exception from within the catch in a way that it's not an Unhandled Promise Rejection?

Comment: Two choices.  1) Don't throw in the first place or 2) Catch the error at a higher level.  We can't be any more specific than that because you aren't showing us the overall structure of this code so we can identify how else you can propagate and catch this error at a higher level.  In case you didn't realize, you don't catch a rejected promise like this with just a try/catch at a higher level.  You have to actually catch rejections on THIS particular promise either at this level or by propagating the rejection to a higher level and catching it there.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am just trying to catch all my errors with process.on('uncaughtException'). How do I propagate the rejection to a higher level?

Comment: `process.on('uncaughtException')` should NEVER be your main method of error handling for any type of error.  By the time an error gets there, your server is in an unknown state.  You propagate a rejected promise to a higher level by returning that promise and then using `.catch()` on it at a higher level.

Comment: well I want to print errors in a consistent fashion, and that's the only way to do it

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to log unhandled promise rejections for diagnostic purposes, you can do that with:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
    console.log('Unhandled Rejection at:', promise, 'reason:', reason);
  // Application specific logging, throwing an error, or other logic here
});
```

See doc [here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection).

As I have said before, this should not be how you actually handle promise rejections.  They should be caught in your own code at a lower level where you have the precise context for the particular operation that created the error.  This code should be for diagnostic debugging only where you then go and fix the actual code that wasn't handling the promise rejection where it is supposed to be handled.

Comment: They are caught in their own code currently, but then they don't get logged properly unless i copy and paste a bunch of shit into every single promise. 

The main problem is you can't create a custom error logging functions because it loses the context.

Comment: @stackers - Errors should be logged where they have meaning, not in one global place.  That's just how code works. You don't have to log them in every single promise. You usually log them at a level for the operation that makes sense and you only log them when the errors are unexpected or unusual. For example, you may have some expected errors that occur when a file is not found that your code already knows may or may not be present. So, if the point of what you're trying to do here is to let errors propagate up to some high level unhandled so you can log them globally, that's a flawed idea.

Comment: @stackers - I've tried to help you here, but it's unclear what else this question means or how to help any further.

Comment: If I catch the unhandledRejection and then kill the process, that would be fine, right?

Comment: @stackers - As a backstop for diagnostics only where you collect information and then put proper error handling where it was supposed to be.  That wouldn't typically be your normal expected code flow.